# Dyld: Library not Loaded Error Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, macos, frameworks, dyld

Hoookay,

So I know I'm about to get a dozen "load the lib dummy" answers to this, but here goes...

junk.framework is exporting some objects of another project (junk.app) so I can use it on a remote.app node on a cluster.  I can compile junk.framework (which I realize means nothing anymore with dynamic loading) and compile and link remote.app to junk.framework.

However, when I run remote.app I get this lovely jewel of an error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libtiff.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/slate/Documents/junk/build/Development/junk.framework/Versions/A/junk
  Reason: image not found
```

I think what is going on is that junk.framework is loading libtiff.dylib from a certain location and it can't find it.  junk.framework is another project I'm working on that I just got to build (finally).

When I `get info` on libtiff.dylib in my junk target it gives me `/Users/slate/Documents/osirix/osirix/Binaries/LibTiff/libtiff.dylib` as a path... and I've got `absolute path` selected.  So why is it not looking there for it?

Uh... why is it looking at @executable_path/../????  Where on earth is that setting so I can change it?

Edit ---

otool -L gives me this:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 677.26.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 949.54.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 12.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/libtiff.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.4.0)
/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.3)
/System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Versions/A/QTKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/Versions/A/QuickTime (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1327.73.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.4.0)
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.1.4)
/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 227.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 32.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 476.19.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 34.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 242.0.0)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The @executable_path setting was specified when libtiff.dylib was built.  (If you build your own dylib or framework, it's the installation directory (INSTALL_PATH) build setting.)  It can be changed with the install_name_tool command.

Comment: AH so that's why I couldn't find it.  Thanks.