# Dyld Error Message: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.2.dylib OSX

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, libusb, dyld

I am trying to release an app for OSX but every time someone runs the app on their machine they get:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/____.app/Contents/MacOS/____
  Reason: image not found
```

The guy on this post suggests it is the path that the package was built with [Dyld: Library not Loaded Error Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975008/dyld-library-not-loaded-error-mac-os)
But even if I build the app with no prefix I still have the issue.

Then I tried to build using:

```
./configure --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-static --prefix=@executable_path/../Frameworks/
```

But that gave a error of an invalid path. I am including the dylib in the package. I have to use libusb 1.0.16RC10 because there is a bug in the newest stable release that breaks mouse and keyboard functionality on the MBP for a short period of time ever time you scan for devices.

Please tell me there is a way to have it included that every use doesnt have to compile their own libUSB.

Comment: "`libusb-1.0.2.dylib`" is not the same thing as "`libusb-1.0.16RC10.dylib`", is it?

Comment: when i compile the code downloaded from the most recent git for 1.0.16 it results in files named 1.0.2

Comment: do you copy your libusb.dylib into your compiled application package?

Comment: yes, it is included in the app package in the framework directory.

Comment: this is a deceptively difficult issue, I recommend reading a few dynamic linker tutorials, especially focused on @rpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you're including your .dylib within the framework directory, now you just need to run the "`install_name_tool`" to point your app to that dylib within the application package, instead of "`/usr/lib`".

To do this, add a "Run Script" build step after the compiling and linking has finished.  And in this build phase, the script will be as simple as:

```
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/libusb-1.0.2.dylib path/to/your/project/libusb-1.0.2.dylib
```

[The tutorial I'm looking at can be found here](http://jayfuerstenberg.com/devblog/how-to-make-a-build-script-for-bundling-dylib-files-into-an-os-x-app).  I hope this helps you out!

Comment: that definitely changed something... now the app just bounces in the tray but never actually starts...

Comment: better check Console.app to see what the OS is complaining about now.

Comment: its odd, absolutely nothing from terminal.

Comment: there must have been something wrong with the app I built, i cleaned a rebuilt and now I am back to square 1.

Comment: sounds like you're getting pretty close to solving it!

Comment: any ideas as to why it would stil get an error if i completely removed all old dylibs and now the current one that is built with the app returns the proper path?

Comment: Are you still seeing the original error as described in your question?

Comment: Yes. That is what I ment by back to square 1

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time there, turns out i had 2 copies of the same lib, one was in /usr/lib/ the other in the build directory. Turns out it takes the one in /urs/lib and not the one you have reference.

THANKS A LOT!